# Can anyone tell me why this gridset css isn't working?

Tags: css

I've used gridsetapp.com in the past to create responsive grids, but on the one I've recently tried creating just isn't working and I can't figure out why.

The link to the css is here; https://get.gridsetapp.com/37722/

Just trying to get something basic:

```
<html><head>

<link href="https://get.gridsetapp.com/37722/" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class="d1-d5" style="background:#aaa">ffggg</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `https://get.gridsetapp.com/37722/` is a directory, and not a css file.

Comment: Based on past experience this usually works, and per their instructions: https://gridsetapp.com/documentation/assets/#downloads Also, the downloaded version doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Despite an unusual CSS link, the browser should recognize the CSS file your referenced.

However, looking at your reference, you are just trying to apply CSS to the class `d1-d5`.  However, as best I can tell, there is no exact match in the CSS file to Just `d1-d5`.  Use the Development tools (F12 on most browsers); they are your friend.  It will show you what CSS is applied *at that moment*  including, any applied through JavaScript or Linked files.

With CSS, you need to make sure that you call out exactly what the browser can identify, but not more (unless going for a higher order of precedence).  For example, the most you could call out to select your `d1-d5` is:

html body div.d1-d5{...}

Whereas in you linked CSS file, I see a lot of parents or children when searching `d1-d5`, such as `.d1-d5 .d1,.d1-d5 .d2,.d1-d5 .d3,.d1-d5 .d4,.d1-d5 .d5`.
If you wanted the last one in this chain (`.d1-d5 .d5`), you would need an HTML such as:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='d1-d5'>
      <div class='d5'>
         This text will have the CSS applied.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS written as `.d1-d5 .d5` literally means "select the element with  class `d5` as a descendent of an element with class `.d1-d5`".  Your HTML doesn't match any of the classes in the CSS file, *including* the parent and child selectors.  If you were to try the above HTML, you would see `width:18.05273834%;` applied (which isn't a very obvious thing to see... why not try `background:yellow;` or something like that for an easy verification).

Finally, why are you inline styling when you have the CSS?  This is bad form, and only appropriate if you can't control the CSS file.